# Maya - Using Python to render a sequence

Tags: python, render, maya

I am making a test render script in Python and am having problems getting my render calls to output sequences, and not just one frame.

I am working in Maya 2015 on a Windows 7 machine.

I have tried using the ogsRender() (Hardware 2.0) and render() (Software Render) commands. And while both of them proclaim to be able to output sequences in the docs, I can't seem to get them to do so.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.render()
cmds.ogsRender()
```

Being a test render script, it doesn't need to be pretty--just fast.

hwRender() (old Hardware Render) seems to work fine, outputting frames according to render settings. However, I get a lot of white artifacts from any intersections when using that render, making it hard to see if things are correct.

Does anyone know how to get render() or ogsRender() to output sequences?

Or maybe remove the white artifacts hwRender() produces?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you post your code? It's hard to diagnose an abstract description.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan

During testing I change render setting to animation and to do frame 1-10.
My script sets the frame range to current work area, and a few other settings - some of which are now outdated since I can't get hwRender to do the job without showing the white artifacts.

[link](https://github.com/Aldwyns/pythonScripts/blob/master/testRender_v1.4.py)

Here is the script in its entirety. The functions startRender() and setSettings() are the relevant ones.
Currently startRender has disabled the calls that don't work for me.

This is my first time posting here. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Just for clarification, any reason you're avoiding the batch render approach? Doing it this way using render() calls would require you to jog the frame each time and fire the call off (e.g. playblast). I'd almost suggest that you'd want to leverage the batch render system, and instead focus on your UI setting the camera/range/render settings, but then again, that might not be what you want..

Comment: @tanantish Well, firstly because its just a tool for some animators to do a quick render in the scene they have open. I felt that it like this gave better feedback on how far the render was, as you can see the timeline move. Also, as I understand it, if you use batch render you will have to use Mel scripts to start your Python scripts. I wanted to avoid the extra clutter if possible. But maybe switching to batch render is the only real solution.

Comment: @JonMurrayVinther If you reaaaaly wanted, you could always script it to fire off frame-by-frame renders via a commandport or something and have a UI element reporting status? The bigger problem in wrangling you a solution is that there's probably a dozen ways to approach the problem and the one that works best is going to depend on your animators etc etc. Using what you have, i'd suggest you're going to have to do your own cmds.currentTime() calls to jog frames and fire off cmds.render() (or lazily cmds.currentTime(cmds.currentTime(q=1)+1) ).

Answer (score 0):

Just incase this is what you're after, here's a rough approach you could use where you jog the frame and make your own batch-ish render system.

The only reason I've used `renderfn` rather than hardcoding `maya.cmds.render` is just incase you wanted to hook into something else (like, I dunno, dropping out some kind of scenefile that you'd feed into a renderfarm or suchlike)

```
import maya.cmds as mc
def render_seq(startframe = 1, endframe = 10, renderfn = mc.render, renderfn_args = None):
    '''render out a sequence of frames as per global settings

    defaults to using maya.cmds.render for frames 1-10'''

    # save state
    now = mc.currentTime(q=True)

    for x in xrange(startframe, endframe):
        mc.currentTime(x)
        renderfn(renderfn_args)

    # restore state
    mc.currentTime(now)
```

Comment: I thought about using this method, but was afraid it might cause the render to take more time because of all the start/stopping. In reality, the difference might be minuscule. I will give it a shot.
What really annoyed me is that ogsRender docs say [LINK](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/ogsRender.html) "Renders an image or a **sequence**", but i could not figure out how to make it output a sequence.

Comment: Alas, output is never as simple as it sounds.